# How is the Unix / PostgreSQL crypt function a trapdoor function?

Tags: terminology, password-hashing, database, trapdoor

I am looking at this in the context of password hashing in PostgreSQL, specifically, the `crypt` function of the [`pgcrypto` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.37.8).

The PostgreSQL documentation refers to the Unix man page of the `crypt` function. The man page (`man 3 crypt`) of the `crypt` function states that it performs Trapdoor encryption. Now a trapdoor function should

1. Be easy to compute in one direction - this I understand.
2. Be hard to compute in the other direction - this I also understand
3. Be easy to compute in the other direction if one knows the 'trapdoor' value - I don't understand if/how one might be able to get this value.

I know how to generate a hash, but how might I be able to get the trapdoor value to compute back the original password? Or are the algorithms written in a way so as to discard the trapdoor value?

It did not make sense to ask this in the dba.stackexchange community, as that's primarily about database design and related topics.

Edit/update -
Only the [BSD man page for `crypt`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?crypt(3)) states it is a Trapdoor function. The [Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) states no such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: `crypt` is not a trapdoor function.

`crypt` does not meet the question's condition 3. It does not apply a trapdoor function, which the question defines correctly at some level of detail. Whether `crypt` *"performs Trapdoor encryption"* depends on the definition given to this. I would not say that.

The cryptographic functions used by `crypt` nowadays are called [[key-stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) | purposely slow] [password-based] hash. On top of this it's also [memory-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-hard_function) when it uses [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) or [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).

Comment: Thanks. The [BSD man page for `crypt`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?crypt(3)) says Trapdoor in the description. On Ubuntu Linux, it only says passphrase hashing.